# jQuery - Onclick append form inputs and assign name attribute

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a jQuery button that every time is pressed appends the inputs below to a form. My problem is that i need a way to also give name attributes (numbers) to the new inputs that jQuery produces.

```
1: <input type="file">
2: <input type="file">
3: <input type="file">
4: <input type="file">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you click on `#button` get the last input and set the new name attribute. Then append the new input element in to the form:

```js
$('#button').on('click', function() {
   var form = $('#form');
   var num = parseInt(form.find('input:last-of-type').attr('name')) + 1;
   form.append('<input type="file" name="' + num + '" />');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="file" name="1" />
</form>

<button id="button">Add new</button>
```

Comment: Basically i have a small problem, When i `console.log(num)`  returns `NaN`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide some code example (jsFiddle) in order for us to be able to help you